# If statement not catching catching condition

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, loops, charts

I'm looping through a list of decimals and I use an if statement to catch any junk data and not chart it if any appears in the list, though the if statement doesn't seem to be catching this and the junk data gets charted anyways. I've tried Continue For and exiting the sub altogether, but it rarely seems to be caught. My code below:

```
For i = 1 To 8
            If hotTemps(i - 1) > 3000 Or hotTemps(i - 1) < -400 Then
                Continue For
            End If
            If celsius.Checked And sysTime.Checked Then
                Chart1.Series(i - 1).Points.AddXY(TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), CDec(hotTemps(i - 1)))
            ElseIf fahrenheit.Checked And sysTime.Checked Then
                Chart1.Series(i - 1).Points.AddXY(TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), CDec((hotTemps(i - 1))) * 1.8 + 32)
            ElseIf celsius.Checked And elapsedTime.Checked Then
                Chart1.Series(i - 1).Points.AddXY(elapsed, CDec(hotTemps(i - 1)))
            ElseIf fahrenheit.Checked And elapsedTime.Checked Then
                Chart1.Series(i - 1).Points.AddXY(elapsed, CDec((hotTemps(i - 1))) * 1.8 + 32)
            End If
Next
```

Comment: The `Or` in the first `If` statement will do it... if either of them are true, then it will continue.

Comment: post the contents of the hottemps array/the definition of the hottemps function

Comment: Well, pretty much a debugging problem so really stepping through the code and inspecting state at each point should give your answer.  One thing I can see though, i = 1 to 8, then you checking if i-1 either greater than 3000 or less than -400.  i is never going to be any where near those upper or lower limits so your Continue For is simply never going to fire

Comment: @Hursey, the comparisons to 3000 and -400 are not made to `i - 1` but rather `hotTemps(i - 1)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney.  Quite right,  will learn to read one day.  Point on debugging still stands though

Comment: There's some ugly stuff going on there. Firstly, you loop from 1 and then subtract 1 from `i` everywhere, so you obviously ought to be looping from 0. Depending on what `hotTemps` actually is, the upper bound probably ought to be `hotTemps.GetUpperBound(0)` or `hotTemps.Count - 1`.

Comment: @SS_DBA, correct. I only want to chart values within that range, so I use Continue For to skip that iteration if the value is greater than 3000 or less than -400, but the If statement doesn't seem to catch values outside that range.

Comment: @jmcilhinney it is a tad messy for the time being, but it should still be functional, no?

Comment: So, why don't you wrap this statement around the other `If` statements `If hotTemps(i - 1) between -400 and 3000` and see what you get. If I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your loop to check your logic.

```
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
    For a = 0 To 7
        If a > 6 Or a < 3 Then
            Continue For
        End If
        lst.Add(a)
    Next
    For Each i In lst
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
```

This produces

```
3
4
5
6
```

Is this the expected result?